Contradictions on limitations of looking and touching slave women during slave market inspection

أخرجه أبو بكر بن أبي شيبة في المصنف ت الشثري (ج11/ص310) حدثنا علي بن
مسهر عن عبيد الله عن نافع عن ابن عمر أنه كان إذا أراد أن يشتري الجارية
وضع يده على أليتيها وبين فخذيها وربما كشف عن ساقيها. وهذا إسناد صحيح
It was narrated by Abu Bakr Ibn Abi Shaybah in Al-Musannaf, edited by
Al-Shathri (vol. 11, p. 310): Ali Ibn Musher narrated to us from
Ubaidullah from Nafi' from Ibn Umar that when he wanted to buy a
female slave, he would place his hand on her buttocks and between her
thighs, and sometimes uncover her legs. And this is a sound chain of
narration.
Islamink


عَبْدُ الرَّزَّاقِ،
١٣٢٠٨ - عَنِ ابْنِ جُرَيْجٍ قَالَ: أَخْبَرَنِي مَنْ أُصَدِّقُ عَمَّنْ،
سَمِعَ عَلِيًّا، يَسْأَلُ عَنِ الْأَمَةِ تُبَاعُ أَيَنْظُرُ إِلَى
سَاقِهَا، وَعَجُزِهَا، وَإِلَى بَطْنِهَا؟. قَالَ: «لَا بَأَسَ
بِذَلِكَ، لَا حُرْمَةَ لَهَا، إِنَّمَا وَقَفَتْ لِنُسَاوِمَهَا»
Abdul Razzaq,
13208 - From Ibn Jurayj, he said: "A trustworthy person told me from whom I trust, that he heard Ali asking about a female slave being sold, whether one should look at her leg, her buttocks, and her belly?" He said: "There is no harm in that, she has no sanctity, she is only standing for us to negotiate her price."
Shamela

My Question is as follows:
I have seen that many scholars limit looking and touching slave women in the markets based on their defined awrah (navel to knee which is impermissible to inspect). But in the above narrations, we can see Ibn Umar (r.a) touching buttocks (over clothes) and touching between thighs but both of those areas fall between navel and knee. Also what does between thighs refer to? Vagina? Also Ali (r.a) is saying it's permissible to look at the buttocks.
We also see in another narration below that a Companion of the prophet said it's not permissible to look at between navel and knee.

صح عن أبي موسى الأشعري أنه قال ألا لا أعرفن أحداً أراد أن يشتري جارية فينظر إلى ما فوق الركبة أو دون السرة لا يفعل ذلك أحد إلا عاقبته
It was authentically reported on the authority of Abu Musa al-Ash’ari that he said: “I do not know anyone who wants to buy a female slave and looks above the knee or below the navel. No one should do that except that I will punish him.”
Islamink

I see in places where Islam restricts slave women inspections to navel and knee then isn't what i stated at the beginning contradicting?

وتبقى ميزة الإسلام في تقييد ذلك بحدود العورة, وأمن الفتنة, وغير ذلك من
الضوابط، على خلاف ما كان معمولًا به في الدنيا بأسرها من إطلاق ذلك
تمامًا. ومن وراء هذا كله يأتي حث الشريعة وترغيبها في عتق الرقيق،
والإحسان إليهم.
And the distinctive feature of Islam remains in restricting that
within the limits of modesty, ensuring the prevention of temptation,
and other regulations, contrary to what was practiced in the entire
world by allowing it completely. And beyond all this comes the
encouragement and urging of Sharia to emancipate slaves and to treat
them kindly.
Islamway

Would like some explanation on this. Thanks.

They are differences of legal opinion not contradictions. It is even reported from some of the tabieen that they said that during appraisal of a slave woman it is permitted to see everything except her genital.
Secondly they are not all equally authentic. The report from Ibn Umar is saheeh. The one from Abu Musa al-Ash’ari is Hassan. The one from Ali has an unidentified narrator.
Thirdly the report of Ibn Umar only states that he uncovered her calves. For the rest it is only stated that he touched those parts and it is stated in versions of the report he touched from behind a cloth.

Hi! Thank you for the answer, two small questions, i understand the inspection part, was parading them bare chested or default display like that for attracting buyers Islamic? Also does any legal opinion allow inspection of genitals and does genitals include both (reproductive organ and anus) or just the reproductive organ?
